# size_t comparison to 0 does not work, comparison to -1 does

Tags: c, comparison, size-t

I'm trying to write extremely simple code to read input from stdin, one line at a time.

The code

```c
size_t size = 0;
size_t length = 1;
char* text = NULL;

while (length > 0) {
    length = getline(&text, &size, stdin);
}
```

Does not terminate on EOF, when `length = -1`, while

```c
while (length != -1) {
    length = getline(&text, &size, stdin);
}
```

does.

How is this at all possible? Thanks.

Comment: `getline()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `size_t`....

Comment: `getline` returns a signed value, `ssize_t` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: And usually when you try to store -1 in an unsigned type, you get a very large positive number.

Comment: You're converting a signed value to an unsigned value.  When comparing an `ssize_t` to a `size_t`, the `ssize_t` value is converted to a `size_t` and an unsigned comparison is performed.  This works for the equality test with `-1`, but doesn't do what you want when comparing for `> 0`, since the only unsigned value that is `<= 0` is `0` itself.

Comment: Assigning `-1` to `size_t` will result in the value being the largest value that can be stored by `size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
size_t length = 1;
```

The return of [getline()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is `ssize_t`, not `size_t`

`ssize_t` is used for functions that can return a negative *error* indications (eg `-1` per definition of `getline()`) or a positive `byte` value. `size_t` should be used only for functions that are limited to returning positive `byte` values.

Use `ssize_t length = 1;` as a replacement declaration.

***Aside*** - In your example you use `EOF` in helping to describe your unexpectedly missing error condition.  As @Jonathan Leffler noted in comments, it is noteworthy that because this is tagged `C` (and not `C++`), and because `getline()` is not part of the standard C libraries, it must be either a `GNU` extension or a `POSIX` implementation.  Both explicitly define the `return` error condition as being represented by `-1` not `EOF`.

- [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) - *"If an error occurs or end of file is reached without any bytes read, getline returns -1."*
- [POSIX](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) - *"...Both functions return -1 on failure to read a line..."*  (the other being `getdelim()`.)

The importance of this fun fact is minimized as there are no systems for which `EOF` is defined as anything other than `-1`. :)

Comment: Technically, `getline()` returns `-1` and not EOF, though I grant you there are essentially no systems where the two values differ.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Expanded on that point.  You are noted as the source of this information :)